# The LinkAssemblies task failed unexpectedly.- Xamarin.Forms (Android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have one project in xamarin forms with following configurations:

Xamarin Forms Version: 2.3.3.193
Compile using Android version: version 15 or above whatever
Minimum Android version: Use Compile using SDK version
Target Android version: User Compile using SDK version
Debugger: .Net(Xamarin)

Build Configuration
Platform Target: Any CPU

I got this error and try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/android-linkassemblies-error) article but not helpful for me.

```
Error The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButtonRenderer::SetBackgroundColors()' in assembly: 'FAB.Droid.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.Support.Design.Widget.FloatingActionButton::SetRippleColor(System.Int32)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() HalalApps.Droid
```

This error is was running very much fine but don't know some time unexpectedly this error come.

Comment: Please check to see if the NuGet packages for the `FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButton` are the same version

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No I don't have any reference of FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButton

Comment: There has to be some component you are using, since this is not standard in Forms